# Is it possible to send messages in AVRO format using log4j2 Kafka appender

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, log4j2, avro

I am working on pushing the logs from a Spring Boot application to Kafka using Log4j2. From my research it is observed that AVRO message format is efficient way to send messages to Kafka.
However when I checked the "org/apache/kafka/log4jappender/KafkaLog4jAppender.java" I see it is using ByteArraySerializer.

```
private static final String KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG = ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG;
private static final String VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG = ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG

props.put(KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
props.put(VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");

this.producer = getKafkaProducer(props);
```

There is another class "org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/mom/kafka/KafkaAppender.java"

Looks like this one supports the Avro serialiser. The below link has an example of log4j2 Kafka Appender, however there is a question asked but not answered. Could you please have a look at it and let me know it is right approach.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201608.mbox/%3CSN2PR05MB24610165F4741F91BD6B2C40B2E10@SN2PR05MB2461.namprd05.prod.outlook.com%3E

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Any Update on this. I am running into a similar issue where I am trying to transform a log into an avro schema then send it to kafka. I am trying to use an extension of abstract layout to format in avro and hoping that works but not having any luck